# Batched updates support in dojo dgrid or slick Grid not available

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, slickgrid, dgrid

I have a requirement where I have lot of data coming in realtime and I need to update the data in a table in html, this data updates are so fast that the dojo dgrid and slick grid have performance issues because it is resulting in lot of dom operations.

I have tried to use the on demand grid feature and it has issues as it is slow when i want to scroll to the end of the page or i keep scrolling continually.

Please let me know if there is a support for batched updates so that I can create fragments and update the data in batches instead of pushing each update to dom directly.

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt that SlickGrid can't keep up with your rate of data updates.  That use case has been specifically tested and designed for.  Could you include more details?  Also, there's a demo that showcases just that - http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example14-highlighting.html

Comment: My updates are like per second it impacts 54 rows out of a total of 540 rows. Also the table is sorted, so when I scroll the next set of viewable data is taking more time to display.

Comment: what i am looking for is to update the complete viewable area at once per second, this will allow me to scroll with out performance issues and while scrolling stop the updates in dom.

Comment: Are all of the impacted rows visible on the same "page", or are they spread out through the dataset?  If you create a test page that simulates the updates and shows the performance issue, I'll be able to take a look.

Comment: Also, SlickGrid only updates the viewable area, and updating the entire area once a second seems perfectly reasonable and doable.

Comment: no all of the impacted areas are not visible on the same page, I want a mechanism where the complete viewable area is updated at once and not when ever there is a update, Please suggest how we can achieve this.

Comment: forgot to mention I want to update the viewable area once per second at once.

Comment: Either way works.  You can set up a timer to invalidate and rerender the whole viewport area, but that would be pretty inefficient since you'd be rerendering rows that haven't changed at all.

Comment: What is the best approach to update viewport area when there are lot of updates in the viewport area, is batch update (i.e update all at once per second) using document.fragment or update one by one when ever there is a update, from my exp what i see if i update continuously I am not able to perform scroll operation properly. because it is not getting processing time. Please comment